# Add a Rails controller from a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am developing a rubygem specifically for Rails applications and I want to add a controller from my gem so that it will be available on the Rails app(Similar to what [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/master/app/controllers/devise) does with RegistrationsController, SessionsController).

**On the gem side:**

I've tried adding the following
app/controllers/samples_controller.rb

```
class SamplesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    .
    .
  end
end
```

And then on my rails routes add it either as:

```
match 'route' => 'samples#index'
```

or

```
resources :samples
```

Clearly I got something wrong over there but I have no idea what is it? Do I need to explicitly require my SampleController somewhere or an initializer on the app?

Right now I am getting this error when accessing the route

```
uninitialized constant SamplesController
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 25):

Let's assume your gem is called MyGem and you have a controller called SamplesController that you want to use in the app. Your controller should be defined as:

```
module MyGem
  class SamplesController < ApplicationController
    def whatever
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

and in your gem directory it should live at app/controllers/my_gem/samples_controller.rb (not under the lib folder).

Then create engine.rb in your gems lib/my_gem folder with code

```
module MyGem
  class Engine < Rails::Engine; end
end
```

You can write routes inside your gem by writing creating routes.rb in config folder with code

```
# my_gem/config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  match 'route' => 'my_gem/samples#index'
end
```

Final structure something like this

```
## DIRECTORY STRUCTURE
#

- my_gem/
  - app/
    - controllers/
      - my_gem/
        + samples_controller.rb
  - config/
    + routes.rb
  - lib/
    - my_gem.rb
    - my_gem/
      + engine.rb
      + version.rb
  + my_gem.gemspec
  + Gemfile
  + Gemfile.lock
```

Thats it.

Comment: mostly correct, one more thing: add `require 'my_gem/engine'` to `lib/my_gem.rb`

Comment: What is the purpose of `./lib/my_gem/engine.rb`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have a typo in your code: `AppicationController` should be `ApplicationController`.

Then, you're not following the Rails naming conventions (plural for resources etc.):

- In your routes it would have to be either `resources :samples` or `resource :sample`.
- Your controller class should be `class SamplesController` and
- the filename of the controller should be `samples_controller.rb`.

Follow the conventions and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks but I still get `uninitialized constant SamplesController`

Comment: Can you double check that your file is named correctly (samples_controller.rb), defines the proper class (class SamplesController < ApplicationController) and is in the proper folder (app/controllers)?

Comment: Yep, just double checked it. Remember that this controller is inside a gem not in the Rails app it self. don't know if that's a problem

Answer (score 0):

to set up your route, create a routes.rb file in the config directory of your project. To have it match on the sample route, do the following:
config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  <resource definition here>
end
```

app/controllers/samples_controller.rb

```
module Samples
  class SamplesController < ApplicationController
    def index
      .
      .
    end
  end
end
```

Remember to include the module in the application controller

```
include 'samples'
```

Have you looked at this site:

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/06/23/a-guide-to-starting-your-own-rails-engine-gem/